# What is the correct way to write refuah shleimah, רפואה שלמה or רפואה שלימה?

Tags: hebrew

What is the correct way to spell refuah shelimah in Hebrew. Is it with a שלמה or שלימה?

Answer (score 5):

Different conventions for spelling are used for different purposes.

Siddurim (prayer books) use [ktiv menuqad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ktiv_menuqad). Vowels are mostly specified by dots, not letters. The form שלמה would be used in a siddur, and the Tzeirei vowel would be indicated by dots.

Modern Israeli newspapers and books use [ktiv male](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ktiv_hasar_niqqud#Ktiv_male). In this system, a lot of Vav's and Yud's are inserted, to help indicate to the reader the vowels to use. In a newspaper, they'd spell your word שלימה.

Comment: Other examples include ציצית instead of ציצת and שבת קודש instead of שבת קדש.